# Characterize this subspace of the bounded operators on $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces, unitary-representations

I posted this on MSE a couple months ago and it got three upvotes but no answers or even comments so I decided to cross-post it here:

For every pair $ a,b $ of real numbers define the operator $ U_{a,b} $ on $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ sending $ \psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ to $ U_{a,b}\psi $ defined by the equation
$$
[U_{a,b}\psi](x)=e^{ibx}\psi(x+a)
$$
Consider the set of operators
$$
\mathcal{B}:=\{ U_{a,b}:a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
Let $ V $ be the closure in the operator norm topology of the span of the set $ \mathcal{B} $. Does anyone have a good idea for a nice characterization of what sort of operators are and are not in $ V $? Does $ V $ include all trace class operators? All compact operators? All unitary operators?

This is a follow up question to my question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303824/is-this-a-basis-for-the-bounded-operators-on-l2-mathbbr

Comment: $(a,b,t)\to e^{it}U_{a,b}$ is the Schrödinger representation of the Heisenberg group. Please see the book *"Harmonic Analysis in Phase Space"* by Folland.

Comment: An easier to read account is Chapter 9 in the book *"Foundations of Time-Frequency Analysis"* by Gröchenig.

Comment: If you'd like to search the literature,$V$ is the CCR = *canonical commutation relations* algebra (not to be confused with CCR = *completely continuous representations* algebra).

Comment: If you're in UMD, Radu Balan is the right person to talk to in person about this C*-algebra.

Comment: Haha funny you should say that I was actually going to send out an email this week to Balan (he's super awesome I took real analysis 2 and functional analysis with him!) asking him to be on the committee for my Oral exam. How did you know I'm at UMD?

Comment: google's crystal orb reveals many secrets. I used to sit at a table in your current umd office at $\phi$th century BC. I consider Radu Balan a star within his research community. He's a nice and knowledgeable person. By the way, I wish the best of luck at your presentation. cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any linear combination $L$ of $U_{a,b}$'s can be written $(L\psi)(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_ke^{ib_kx}\psi^{\to a_k}(x)$, where $\psi^{\to a_k}(x) = \psi(x + a_k)$. Fix $L$.

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $Nb_k$ is close to an integer multiple of $2\pi$, for all $k$. Then $$(L\psi^{\to N})(x) = \sum \alpha_k e^{ib_kx}\psi^{\to a_k + N}(x) = (\sum \alpha_k e^{ib_k(x - N)}\psi^{\to a_k}(x))^{\to N} = (\sum \alpha_k'e^{ib_kx}\psi^{\to a_k}(x))^{\to N}$$ where each $\alpha_k'$ is close to $\alpha_k$. Okay, now find a sequence $N_j \to \infty$ such that as $j \to \infty$ the multiples $N_jb_k$ get arbitrarily close to integer multiples of $2\pi$. Then $(L\psi^{\to N_j})^{-N_j} \to L\psi$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, for every $\psi$.

But any compact operator $T$ satisfies $T\psi^{\to N_j} \to 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Taking $\psi$ with $\|\psi\|_2 = 1$ and $\|L\psi\|_2$ close to $\|L\|$, we have $\|T\psi^{\to N_j}\|_2 \to 0$ but $\|L\psi^{\to N_j}\|_2 \to \|L\psi\|_2 \cong \|L\|$. This shows you that $\|T - L\| \geq \|L\|$; that is, the distance from $L$ to the compact operators is $\|L\|$. Every element of $V$ will have the same property, so in particular $V$ contains no compact operators besides $0$.

Every operator is a linear combination of four unitaries, so if $V$ contained every unitary then it would be all of $B(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$, which we've just seen is not the case. On the other hand, the WOT closure of $V$ does equal $B(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$; this follows from the double commutant theorem, since any operator that commutes with $U_{0,b}$ for all $b$ must be a multiplication operator and hence won't commute with $U_{a,0}$ for all $a$ unless it is a scalar. That is, $V' = \mathbb{C}\cdot I$, so $V'' = B(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: BTW, as Onur Oktay points out, you have described a [CCR algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras) (over the symplectic space $\mathbb{C}$ with symplectic form $\{a,b\} = {\rm Im}(a\bar{b})$). It is known that these algebras are always simple (noted in the above link), so that's another reason they can't contain any compact operators. Otherwise the intersection with the compacts would be a nontrivial ideal.